# Windows Subsystem for Linux ssh issue

Tags: linux, ssh, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Context**

I am using Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) on 2 different computers, and I want to ssh from one to another, and vice-versa.
Both computers are on the same network, so they can communicate directly through their private IP. This is all in order to use them later in a master-slave pattern for parralelized tasks, so I'll be calling one computer master and the other slave ( although this is still irreleveant at this point). I did not set up connection via keys yet (well, I have but I backed off and re-installed everything since then)

**Problem:**

I *can* log in:

- from the slave to the master
- from the slave to the slave (via ssh localhost, or directly ssh XXX.XXX.X.XXX)
- from the master to the master (ssh localhost or IP)

I *can not* login from the master to the slave. I get the Following error:

`ssh: connect to host slave1 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable`

**EDIT:** tried with a third computer. the 3rd computer can log into master and vice versa. Slave can log into the 3rd computer, but the 3rd computer *can not* log into slave. So it seems the problem comes from the slave computer which can not "receive" ssh. (it is good reminding that the slave can ssh into itself with no problem though).

Also I have noticed something that may or may not play a role: the output of `ifconfig` in the slave gives me a mysterious `eth1` section, up and running, even though no ethernet cable is connected to the computer. This does not happen for the other computers. The slave computer is anyway connected to the same wifi as the other ones, and it is with that IP that I intend to ssh into it.

I have tried to completely disable firewall on the slave, but it does not seem to solve the issue

**Attempted solutions:**

Now, I've found a lot of material adressing the issue of ssh on WSL, but none of the fixes worked for me. Here is a (non-exhaustive) list of what I tried unfruitfully, as advised from different sources:

- adding a rule to the firewall of the slave to allow port 22
- disabling Windows ssh services on the slave to avoid conflicts
- uninstalling/reinstalling the `openssh-client` / `openssh-server`
- insulting the whole family of my computer
- setting `PasswordAuthentication yes` in the sshd_config file, setting `UsePrivilegeSepration no`
- adding this weird line to the sshd_config file:

`Host *
    ProxyCommand nc %h %p %r`

- finding heavier insults

**Current situation**

I just purged and reinstalled the ssh packages from both computer, with no adjustement. the situation is still exactly the same as described in the problem: slave has no problem connecting to master or itself, but master cant connect to slave.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can the master connect to yet another server? Can yet another client connect to the slave? Boot live CD/USB Linux on the slave/master if you lack yet another host.

Comment: I brought a 3rd computer to check this. It seems the problem is due to the slave computer